# An Incredible Theory

Tags: riddle, rhyme, knowledge

I am still relatively new to the Puzzling section of Stack Exchange; but with a single puzzle under my belt, I'm back with another one. It took me some time to put this one together and it has been heavily influenced by a research project. I have broken this puzzle into three parts; I tried to tie them together as much as possible. Your goal is to solve the puzzle with ***as few parts as possible***, keeping in mind that the answer is **two** words.

**Part One**:

> My prefix is an argument.
>
> My suffix is an emmet.
>
> My infix is an acronym.
>
> I am a synonym.

**Part Two**:

> Your first thought is an animal, your second is a sin; what you truly desire is an antonym.

***Part Two's Hint***:

> In reality the word you seek is a synonym of an antonym. You'll have to work hard to locate it, or simply solve the following riddle;
>
>  I am never still yet never resting.
>
>  I move to and from at the same time.
>
>  I am governed by a trinity.
>
>  What am I?

**Part Three**:

> Theorized for ages, on millions of pages, research seems unabating.
>
>  Many desire, to solve but tire, the laws of physics keep confuting.

Hopefully this wasn't too terrible. Good luck, and feel free to let me know what you think!

Comment: Hi there! Were all of the parts meant to be hidden, or were they all meant to be open, or was just the first one supposed to be open?

Comment: Just the first as to not spoil the second and third parts for those who enjoy the challenge of attempting to solve in as few parts as possible.

Comment: So all three parts relate to the same answer? (ie. there's only one answer to this puzzle, and it can be solved through Part 1?)

Comment: If you solve part one and do some research on the answer you can solve the riddle there. Part two is a hint that adds to part one, then part three is a major clue as to what the answer is. Yes, all three parts relate to the same answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's see if I can make some progress...

My prefix is an argument.

> Could this be a CON, as in pros and cons?

My suffix is an emmet.

> An emmet is an archaic word for ANT.

My infix is an acronym.

> The acronym ST is a mathematical acronym for "subject to" or "such that".

I am a synonym.

> A CONSTANT is a synonym for a quantity, or a given, or a parameter...

When doing some thinking on

> constants, one major research problem that I remember reading about was with regards to the cosmological constant problem, which refers to massive differences in energy related to the Big Bang and expansion of the Universe. Could you be talking about the cosmological constant problem?

Since part 2 is supposed to add clarity, we can see that

> we need a word which means both an animal and a deadly sin...this word is likely SLOTH; but it says that we need an antonym to this. If DRIVE is not the antonym, perhaps it is ENERGY instead...if not ENERGY, then why not MOTION (since it is governed by Newton's 3 laws, and is never still/always moving).

Then maybe what you're dealing with

> is the theory of PERPETUAL MOTION, since it is an incredible theory, yet seemingly anything produced violates the First/Second Law of Thermodynamics and so nothing has actually been created. Also, this research has led me to start reading about [time crystals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_crystal) which look pretty darn cool!

Comment: Your work so far has you on the right track but not quite the answer.

Comment: Is my part 1 correct?

Comment: It is indeed, part 2 will add clarity when coupled with part 1's results. You'll have to work hard to figure out part 2 however as it is not a common answer.

Comment: I think what I'll do is try to clarify part two with an added hint as even tracing backwards it's difficult to locate the answer without previous knowledge.

Comment: Your updates have you on fire here! If I could up-vote a second time I would!

Comment: Thanks!! Have I figured out part 2?

Comment: You're incredibly close on part two, even your guess at the answer is a big part of the topic at hand with this theory. I updated my post to include an easier riddle for part 2 as my riddle may have not been the best there.

Comment: @davisj1691 are you actually doing work on these? Or just thermodynamics, etc. in general?

Comment: Writing a paper on the mechanics behind the theory. Thermodynamics just disproves it. I tend to believe the theory is possible and that it can be achieved while following the laws of thermodynamics.

Comment: That's really cool! Did I get it then? If so, [obligatory Simpsons reference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gOMibx876A4) :D

Comment: Good luck on your paper! I hope that the topic turns out well for you :)

Comment: Right now it is a tie between you and m1go0z on a miniscule technicality. I would love to just blurt out what the technicality is here, but unfortunately it would display the answer to the riddle in plain sight. Also, thanks for the luck! I'm going to need it!

Comment: If we're talking about theory....then this might be technically right?

Comment: Correct! I've been wanting to bold, italicize, and underline the word theory for what feels like an eternity here. :D The machines themselves are not what I am studying, but the theory of perpetual motion in which motion continues indefinitely.

Comment: Time crystals are fantastic by the way; just caught that update. I hope you enjoyed the puzzle, it took me a few days to come up with. Which is probably time that I should have spent working on my math!

Comment: Haha once I thought about theory, I figured that a physics researcher would deal with perpetual motion itself....the [actual machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perpetual_motion) being largely the domain of 1800-1900s snake-oil salesmen.

Comment: @davisj1691 I would never have discovered them without this puzzle -- thanks very much for creating it! I learned a lot about thermodynamics in the past little while....which is time I should have spent working on my math as well! :P C'est la vie! :)

Comment: @El-Guest, great job!  Agree that this was an awesome puzzle, @davis1961!

Answer (score 7):

Building on El-Guest:

> I agree the first word is Constant so the next word is "Animal or Sin" in the seven deadly sins, one is "Sloth" which is an animal. One opposite of sloth is "Drive". So "Constant Drive" which doesn't make sense, so lets go with "Constant-Acceleration Drive"

Comment: This is a great answer, and super cool too!! :D

Comment: I would love to say this is the answer since this would've been a great research project; unfortunately it is not. +1 From me.

Answer (score 2):

Is it a

> <del>Constant Motion Machine</del> Constant Energy Machine

Building on [El-Guest](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/50778/el-guest)'s partial answer

> Part II makes me think of how slow Sloth's are to move but the antonym may be a perpetual <del>motion</del> energy 
>  Part III deals with a physical impossibility, which a constant energy machine has not been created

Update

> A constant motion machine requires endless energy input, so I changed my answer to the energy instead.

Comment: Incredibly close here! I want to mark this as the answer; however, by a miniscule technicality it isn't. I can say you're on the rim of the nail head here.

Comment: Interesting input, I have made a change but that's definitely worth a thought

Comment: Still on the rim of the nail head.

Comment: @Kevorobin Not sure how to decrypt that.

Comment: @davisj1691 [rot13.com](https://www.rot13.com)

Comment: Updated again.  Hopefully, this will hit the nail and not just the rim.

Comment: Your first and second guesses where closer to the theory in question.